# How to create a C++ library in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

[Here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081112125751AApVBrX) a person asks "How to make your own library in C++ ?". This is exactly the question that I have. There is an answer to this question:

> 1. Create the files "mylibrary.h" and "mylibrary.cpp".
> 2. Only compile the library, and it shouldn't have a "main()" function in
>      it. This step will generate an object file called "myfile.o".
> 3. Create another file called something like "main.cpp". In main.cpp
>      you need to #include "mylibrary.h".
> 4. Compile main.cpp and add the library from step 2 to link in (in this case "myfile.o"). If you don't add this library, you'll get a
>      error message like "linker error - can't find function definition", or
>      something like that.

But I still have some questions:

1. The Library.cpp should have a `main()` function. But what should be in this main function? I do not want my library to execute something by default, when my program starts. I want it to contain a set of functions that are executed only when they are called explicitly.
2. In the step 4, it is written that I need to "Compile main.cpp and add the library from step 2", but I have already compiled the library on the step 2. Should I compile it one more time?
3. What does "in this case 'myfile.o'" mean? What exactly should I do with "myfile.o" in this case?
4. On the step 4 it is written "If you don't add this library, you'll get a error message". But what does "to add library" mean? On step 3 I put `#include "mylibrary.h"` into the main.cpp, so I have added the library? Or I need to do something more to add the library?

Could you please help me to understand the answer?

---

**ADDED:** I think I need to use Eclipse to generate `.a`, `.lib`, `.so`, or `.dll` files? Does anyone know how I can do it and what exactly I should generate?

Comment: The stuff about `main` in that answer is an example of how to use the library.

Comment: @yiding, do you mean main.cpp or main() in the Library.cpp?

Comment: You don't need a main function in the library.

Comment: @yiding, then the answer was wrong? Because it says "compile the library, and it shouldn't have a "main()" function in it"?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't. as in you should write one.

Comment: 'Shouldn't' is an abbreviation of 'should not'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example, consider a "library" which provides the factorial function. For simplicity, I use free functions.

```
// factorial.h
int factorial(int input);

// factorial.cpp
#include "factorial.h"

int factorial(int input) {
    if(input > 0) return input * factorial(input - 1);
    else if(input == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Now compile these files to generate a `factorial.o`, but do not link. (Configure the Eclipse build command accordingly. If using gcc, use the `-c` and `-o` flags appropriately. Refer compiler documentation to understand what these flags do.)

Next create a `main.cpp` (you can actually name it anything you like.)

```
// main.cpp
#include "factorial.h"

int main() {
    // use your library code here to make sure it is usable and working.  
    factorial(3);
    factorial(5); 
    // etc. 
}
```

Now compile this to a `main.o`, then link this together with the `factorial.o` from earlier to generate the executable. You can actually skip the intermediate `main.o` step, and do both of this in one step with the appropriate compiler options.

Comment: thank you for the answer. What does "link" mean? I mean what "compile but do not link" and "link main.o and factorial.o" mean?